# Your project's Cloud Firestore database '(default)' has insecure rules

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Why am I getting this error? I have pasted my rules below. I have implemented these rules for both storage and cloud firestore.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
      allow write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: where has your error message been displayed?

Comment: in the notifications (bell icon) there was a red dot when I opened it I saw the error message

Answer (score 1):

These are automated alerts by firebase. IMHO sometimes they are false positives. In this case, they deemed it insecure because

> any logged-in user can read your entire database

If this is the intended behavior you can safely ignore this alert. Otherwise, create more precise rules for each collection/document.